# Replace string having , with $

Tags: javascript, regex

Below is my string.When I console b it is showing as below output:

```
var a='602,315,805,887,810,863,657,665,865,102,624,659,636';
var b = a.replace(',',"$");
console.log(b);
```

output:

```
602$315,805,887,810,863,657,665,865,102,624,659,636
```

What should I do to replace complete commas in string to $.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use regexp, `/,/g` with [global](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Guide/Regular_Expressions#Advanced_Searching_With_Flags) flag

```
var a ='602,315,805,887,810,863,657,665,865,102,624,659,636';
var b = a.replace(/,/g,"$");
```

[Example](http://jsbin.com/bilaqo/1/edit?js,console)

Answer (score 0):

```
str.replace(/,/g,"$");
```

will replace `,` with `$`

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/hunAx/383/)**

Answer (score 0):

This question already has an answer anyway i have provide a different approach

```
var var a ='602,315,805,887,810,863,657,665,865,102,624,659,636';
var change= '$'
a= a.split(',').join(change);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use String methods `.split()` and `.join()` to make an array then glue the pieces back together.

```
var b = a.split(',').join('$');
```